# Is it possible to use PostgreSQL anonymous block (PL/pgSQL) within the @Query annotation of Spring Data JPA Repository?

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, plpgsql

I need to call an anonymous block with parameters.

```
@Repository
public interface FinAccountRepository extends JpaRepository<FinAccount, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
            "DO $$ <<credit_account>>\n" +
            "DECLARE\n" +
            "    nNewBalance numeric(19,2);\n" +
            "    nNewId bigint;\n" +
            "BEGIN\n" +
            "    update fin_account set balance = balance + :amount where id = :account\n" +
            "    returning balance into nNewBalance;\n" +
            "    select nextval('seq_fin_account_def_id') into nNewId;\n" +
            "    insert into fin_account_definition(id, account, transaction, balance)\n" +
            "    values (nNewId, :account, :tx, nNewBalance); \n" +
            "END credit_account $$;")
    void credit(@Param("tx") UUID tx, @Param("account") Long account, @Param("amount") BigDecimal amount);

}
```

The following code throws errors

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query; SQL [DO $$
DECLARE
    nNewBalance numeric(19,2);
BEGIN
    update fin_account set balance = balance - :amount where id = :account 
    returning fa.balance into nNewBalance;
    insert into fin_account_definition(id, account, transaction, balance)
    values (nextval('seq_fin_account_def_id'), :account, :tx, nNewBalance);
END $$;]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

. . .

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

. . .

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:69) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setLiteralParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:128) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindLiteral(PgPreparedStatement.java:1042) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setNumber(PgPreparedStatement.java:520) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setBigDecimal(PgPreparedStatement.java:337) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setBigDecimal(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.NamedParamBinder.bind(NamedParamBinder.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    ... 160 common frames omitted
```

Also i tried to use ordinal parameters - the result is the same.
However, an anonymous block without bind parameters is called correctly.
I am interested in the ability to pass parameters to an postgresql anonymous block from method of Spring Data JPA Repository.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PL/pgSQL for this. This can be done in a single SQL statement:

```
with changed_account as (
   update fin_account 
      set balance = balance + :amount 
   where id = :account
   returning balance, id
)            
insert into fin_account_definition(id, account, transaction, balance)
select nextval('seq_fin_account_def_id'), c.id, :tx, c.balance
from changed_account c;
```